# Restrict mobile phones to specific Access Point (WIFI Router)

Tags: authentication, wifi, android, wireless, iphone

Is it possible to restrict the access of android phones, iphone, and MS phones and tablets to a specific AP?

I want the corporate mobile device to only be able connect to one specific AP (the corporate WIFI LAN) and I don't want the user of the device to be able to change this.  These are not personal devices (not BYOD).

If the question isn't perfectly clear, I mean that the mobile devices listed should only be able to connect to one wifi router and no other wifi router / access point should be connectable to device by any action the end user takes.

Comment: You can't. It is under the user's jurisdiction whose network he wants to join. At home he can join his access point and at workplace he can join yours. Attacker can also force him to join rogue wifi.

Comment: @defalt , the devices are work devices only.  People don't take them off premises.  They don't take them home.

Comment: You need to look at MDM solutions. Some of these may be able to provide want you are seeking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I know using Apple Configurator it is possible to set a restriction on managed devices to "Join only Wi-Fi networks installed by a Wi-Fi payload" which effectively limits the SSIDs the device can connect to, and the authentication methods to use.

This comes with the obvious health warning that, if the network the device is restricted to goes down or is unavailable/misconfigured, you will be unable to manage the device.

https://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.5/#/apdf01626ea7

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution like many of the commentors have recommended, you could create an AP for mobile devices and set a policy to restrict the type devices that connect to this AP. 
See the AirWatch MDM solution's documentation on Enrollment Restriction. A similar option might exist for the most MDMs

If you have an Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution like many of the commentors have recommended, you could create an AP for mobile devices and set a policy to restrict the type devices that connect to this AP. 
See the AirWatch MDM solution's documentation on how they do Enrollment Restriction. A similar option might exist for the most MDMs:

https://my.air-watch.com/help/9.1/en/Content/Core_Guides/MDM/T/SaveEnrollmentRestrictionasaPolicy.htm?TocPath=ENROLLMENT%7CDevice%20Enrollment%20(General)%7CAdditional%20Enrollment%20Restrictions%7C_____4

Answer (score 0):

You can only force devices to connect to specific networks if you have control of the device. For example if ts a works device.

If it’s a personal employee phone then they can choose any network they have authentication details for to connect to.

If you mean you want to restrict them to one specific AP that exists within a wider number of APs all connected to the same network then MAC filtering would work here

Comment: the devices are work only devices.  You say this is possible.  How can this be done?

Comment: You need to have them managed by a central policy system for mobile devices. There are lots out there. I’ve heard of https://www.manageengine.com/mobile/ but have never used it myself.